# Avoiding singularity in analysis - does OpenMDAO automatically enable 'fully-simultaneous' solution?

Tags: openmdao, simultaneous, coupling

Turbulent boundary layer calculations break down at the point of flow separation when solved with a prescribed boundary layer edge velocity, u<sub>e</sub>, in what is called the direct method.

[image: Direct method]

This can be alleviated by solving the system in a fully-simultaneous or quasi-simultaneous manner. Details about both methods are available here (https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/14407586/root.pdf), pages 38 onwards. Essentially, the fully-simultaneous method combines the inviscid and viscous equations into a single large system of equations, and solves them with Newton iteration.

[image: Fully-simultaneous method]

I have currently implemented an inviscid panel solver entirely in ExplicitComponents. I intend to implement the boundary layer solver also entirely with ExplicitComponents. I am unsure whether coupling these two groups would then result in an execution procedure like the direct method, or whether it would work like the fully-simultaneous method. I note that in the OpenMDAO paper, it is stated that the components are solved "as a single nonlinear system of equations", and that the reformulation from explicit components to the implicit system is handled automatically by OpenMDAO.

Does this mean that if I couple my two analyses (again, consisting purely of ExplicitComponents) and set the group to solve with the Newton solver, I'll get a fully-simultaneous solution 'for free'? This seems too good to be true, as ultimately the component that integrates the boundary layer equations will have to take some prescribed u<sub>e</sub> as an input, and then will run into the singularity in the execution of its compute() method.

If doing the above would instead make it execute like the direct method and lead to the singularity, (briefly) what changes would I need to make to avoid it? Would it require defining the boundary layer components implicitly?

Answer (score 2):

despite seeming too good to be true, you can in fact change the structure of your system by changing out the top level solver.

If you used a [NonlinearBlockGS](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.6.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/nonlinear/nonlinear_block_gs.html) solver at the tope, it would solve in the weak form. If you used a [NewtonSolver](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.6.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/nonlinear/newton.html) at the top, it would solve as one large monolithic system. This property does indeed derive from the unique structure of how OpenMDAO stores things.

There are some caveats. I would guess that your panel code is implemented as a set of intermediate calculations broken up across several components. If thats the case, then the NewtonSolver will be treating each intermediate variable as it it was its own state variable. In other words, you would have more than just `delta` and `u_e` as states, but also all the intermediate calculations too.

This is might be somewhat unstable (though it might work just fine, so try it!). You might need a hybrid between the weak and strong forms, that can be achieved via the [`solve_subsystems` option on the NewtonSolver](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.6.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/nonlinear/newton.html#newtonsolver-options). This approach, is called the [Hierarchical Newton Method in section 5.1.2 of the OpenMDAO paper](http://file:///Users/jsgray/Downloads/Gray2019_Article_OpenMDAOAnOpen-sourceFramework%20(4).pdf). It will do a sub-iteration of NLBGS for every top level Newton iteration. This acts as a form of nonlinear preconditioner which can help stabilize the strong form. You can limit ho many sub-iterations are done, and in your case you may want to use just 2 or 3 because of the risk of singularity.

Comment: How exactly is this possible if the component would hit the singularity in the compute() method? It (roughly) takes an input of edge velocities and an array of distances, then marches the differential equations along the distances. As I understand it, this process reaches a singularity at the point of separation. Does OpenMDAO somehow sidestep the compute() function, or did I make it seem like my component works differently?

Comment: Its possible that I am not fully understanding. I assumed the equations were identical between the two methods. However, your description of "one time marches and the other doesnt" implies that there is a different mathematical formulation for the integration at work. In other words, the governing equations are posed differently. If that is the case, then OpenMDAO doesn't do magic. It can change the way a given set of equations are solved, but can't change the equations themselves

Comment: I think that what you said is correct if I define the component implicitly - I'll update this question at some point with my implicit formulation and see whether it'd be possible with an explicit one.